# I need to sent form data with mailprogram opened with jQuery

Tags: jquery, mailto

I have a form submitted by $.post but in this script I can open also a e-mailprogram. But I want to sent the inserted form data also with my e-mailprogram. So a screens open where I can sent email but I try to fill this with the data which is formed like this:

```
{action: "https://url.to.sent.data/post/" data: "timestamp=2019-03-25&totaly-early-lens=20"method: "post"}
```

So Timestamp has a value and totaly-yearly-lens has also a value. Does amyone know how to send this to the mail body?

Answer (score 0):

In your success/done of $.post you can try something like this:

```
window.location.href = "mailto:youremail@email.com?body=your+email+body";
```

Comment: I did that but then mailprograms opens with empty body

Comment: I have the data of the form stored in a const formData. When I use your "mailto:myemail@yours.org?body=" + JSON.stringify(formData); the whole data string is in the body. With only the first value (timestamp) anyone experience with this?